JSON parser should reject invalid values for Boolean properties instead of converting to false
Using Micronaut Serde, any string value other than "true" returns false, and any numeric value other than 0 returns true.
Is this desirable behavior or should I open an issue?
For example, reading string values ​​"", "True", "TRUE" or "enabled" from a JSON returns false, which can generate erroneous entries in an API.
Actual Behaviour
Comparing with Javascript behavior, if you run JSON.parse("True") or JSON.parse("TRUE") in the browser console, an exception will be thrown: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'T', "True" is not valid JSON. According to the JSON specification, the expected values ​​are true or false, without quotes. If we wanted to strictly follow the specification, no string values ​​would be allowed.
import io.micronaut.serde.ObjectMapper
import io.micronaut.serde.annotation.Serdeable
import io.micronaut.test.extensions.spock.annotation.MicronautTest
import jakarta.inject.Inject
import spock.lang.Specification

@MicronautTest
class CurrentBehaviorOfBooleanSerdeSpec extends Specification {

    @Inject ObjectMapper objectMapper

    // All asserts in this method are passing
    void "test current behavior"() {
        expect:
        objectMapper.readValue('{"enabled": true}', Test).enabled == true
        objectMapper.readValue('{"enabled": "true"}', Test).enabled == true
        objectMapper.readValue('{"enabled": false}', Test).enabled == false
        objectMapper.readValue('{"enabled": "false"}', Test).enabled == false

        // If there is at least one uppercase letter, returns false, even if the value is true
        // It is acceptable because true or false as a string is not in the Json specification
        objectMapper.readValue('{"enabled": "True"}', Test).enabled == false
        objectMapper.readValue('{"enabled": "TRUE"}', Test).enabled == false

        // Any numeric value other than 0 returns true
        objectMapper.readValue('{"enabled": 0}', Test).enabled == false
        objectMapper.readValue('{"enabled": 1}', Test).enabled == true
        objectMapper.readValue('{"enabled": 99}', Test).enabled == true

        // Any string value other than true returns false
        objectMapper.readValue('{"enabled": ""}', Test).enabled == false
        objectMapper.readValue('{"enabled": " "}', Test).enabled == false
        objectMapper.readValue('{"enabled": "enabled"}', Test).enabled == false
    }

    @Serdeable
    static class Test {
        Boolean enabled
    }

}

Expected Behaviour
All commands in "test expected behavior with invalid values" should throw an exception instead of returning true or false.
import io.micronaut.serde.ObjectMapper
import io.micronaut.serde.annotation.Serdeable
import io.micronaut.serde.exceptions.InvalidPropertyFormatException
import io.micronaut.test.extensions.spock.annotation.MicronautTest
import jakarta.inject.Inject
import spock.lang.Specification

@MicronautTest
class ExpectedBehaviorOfBooleanSerdeSpec extends Specification {

    @Inject ObjectMapper objectMapper

    // All asserts in this method are passing
    void "test expected behavior with valid values"() {
        expect:
        objectMapper.readValue('{"enabled": true}', Test).enabled == true
        objectMapper.readValue('{"enabled": "true"}', Test).enabled == true
        objectMapper.readValue('{"enabled": false}', Test).enabled == false
        objectMapper.readValue('{"enabled": "false"}', Test).enabled == false

        // Could only accept numeric values 0 and 1
        objectMapper.readValue('{"enabled": 0}', Test).enabled == false
        objectMapper.readValue('{"enabled": 1}', Test).enabled == true
    }

    // All asserts in this method are failing
    void "test expected behavior with invalid values"() {
        when:
        // Any string value other than true or false could throw an exception, instead of returning false
        objectMapper.readValue('{"enabled": "True"}', Test).enabled
        objectMapper.readValue('{"enabled": "TRUE"}', Test).enabled
        objectMapper.readValue('{"enabled": "False"}', Test).enabled
        objectMapper.readValue('{"enabled": "FALSE"}', Test).enabled
        objectMapper.readValue('{"enabled": ""}', Test).enabled
        objectMapper.readValue('{"enabled": " "}', Test).enabled
        objectMapper.readValue('{"enabled": "enabled"}', Test).enabled

        // Any numeric value other than 0 and 1 could throw an exception, instead of returning true
        objectMapper.readValue('{"enabled": 99}', Test).enabled

        then:
        thrown(InvalidPropertyFormatException)
    }

    @Serdeable
    static class Test {
        Boolean enabled
    }

}


As far as I know it uses Jackson for doing the actual parsing.
And that's just how Jackson does it.
At https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-serialization/blob/2.10.x/serde-jackson/src/main/java/io/micronaut/serde/jackson/JacksonDecoder.java#L296 it calls getValueAsBoolean() on the Jackson parser and at https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.html#getValueAsBoolean() you see that this is exactly the described behavior:

Method that will try to convert value of current token to a boolean. JSON booleans map naturally; integer numbers other than 0 map to true, and 0 maps to false and Strings 'true' and 'false' map to corresponding values.
If representation can not be converted to a boolean value (including structured types like Objects and Arrays), default value of false will be returned; no exceptions are thrown.

What the JSON spec specifies for boolean values is not so much relevant, as regarding the JSON it is just a String, so you would have String enabled in your POGO. By having Boolean enabled you explicitly ask for trying to convert the value to a boolean value and that is how it is done.
I did not use Serde before, but from a quick look at its documentation at https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-serialization/latest/guide/#serdes I guess you can use a custom serializer that only accepts native boolean JSON values and does not try to convert other things to booleans or throws an exception.
